# Resize player UIView to full screen (from table header)

Tags: ios, swift

I have to implement a few different players to my app (Vimeo, AOL..). I'm adding players to uiview (inside a table header) and I have to implement custom full screen button on the top of the player, but I cannot change size of the view to be a full screen size, bigger than the size of the table header (player parent). I can go to parent VC, remove player, add it to parent VC with with new size. 
Do you know how, for e.g. YT player can go to the full screen size even if it is a uiview? How can YT player uiview become bigger than a parent uiview?

Thanks in advance,
Milos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to present in the root window frame?

```
func show() {
    let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    window!.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert
    window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    window!.rootViewController = self

    self.view.frame = window!.bounds

    window!.addSubview("VIEW TO BE ADDED")
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```